# Calling Case within map function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wish to call specific component based on a data type.

```
{programs.map(p=>(
        p.targets.map(t=> 
          { console.log(t.targetName)
            switch(t.targetName){
            case 'abc':{
                
                (
                <ProgramCard name={p.programName} id={p.id} tname={t.targetName} phase={t.targetPhase}></ProgramCard>
                )
                break;
            }
            default:
                (
                <ProgramCard1 name={p.programName} id={p.id} tname={t.targetName} phase={t.targetPhase}></ProgramCard1>
                )
          }
          }
          )
      ))}
```

when I do console.log I do see values abc, def, def, def.

I was expecting I will see <ProgramCard>, <ProgramCard1>, <ProgramCard1>, <ProgramCard1>

However, nothing is seen. Feel like I am missing something basic but cant figure.

Comment: you have to `return` the component

Comment: thanks...on hindsight not sure how I missed that :)